# How to attach a router to an express app based on a path specified by a regular expression?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

With this very simple app:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port = 8080;

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Test was hit')
})

// binds router to express app
app.use('/root', router);

app.listen(port, () => logger.info(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

After running `curl http://localhost:8080/root/test`, unsurprisingly, the response is `Test was hit`

I am to make this much more generic and wish for the consumer to be able to hit `curl http://localhost:8080/<whatever-the-consumer-specifies>/test` and still hit the routers `/test` endpoint.

However, if I replace the binding to be as follows:

```
app.use('/*',router);
```

After a subsequent hit the response is `Cannot GET /root/test`

How can I instead achieve this?

*** EDIT: ***

Of course I could do:

```
router.get('*/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Test was hit')
})
```

However - This is not the answer that I seek, I only want this configuration take place once in the project.

Comment: `router.get('*/test', ...)`, `app.user('/', router)` should work

Comment: The thing is I do not want to use the asterix in front of each path. I want to only specify this regex once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express allows the use of regular expression in the router middleware as mentioned in the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#path-examples).

```
app.use(/\/\w+/, router);
```

You could replace the string and place a regex in the first argument.